# React code includes Function() eval which chrome extensions does not allow

Tags: google-chrome-extension, reactjs

Is there a way to disable such features in React?
(e.g. in Angular you can use ngScp:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp )

***More details***

Use case: Developing chrome extensions with React.

Chrome extensions have a security policy that doesn't allow eval() code. I can disable the security policy in the manifest.js but then i'm exposed to XSS attacks which i don't wanna do.

Comment: what is your use case ?

Comment: use case: Developing chrome extensions with React.

Comment: Chrome extensions have a security policy that doesn't allow eval() code.  I can disable the security policy in the manifest.js but then i'm exposed to XSS attacks which i don't wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the

`devtool: 'eval',`

in your webpack.config.js to disable function eval.